# insert null value when no selected value from ddl

Tags: c#

I had ddl which determine gender and user can donot choose any value from ddl so i tried to check if user didnot select any value from ddl inser null value or any value in database i made that but error apear(Procedure or Function 'InsertRegisteration' expects parameter '@Gender_Id', which was not supplied).any one help me

(My Code)

```
 if (DDLGender.SelectedItem.Value[0]!= null )
  {
    command.Parameters.Add("@Gender_Id",SqlDbType.Int).Value=null;
  }
  else
  {
    command.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@Gender_Id", DDLGender.SelectedValue));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (DDLGender.SelectedItem.Value[0]!= null ) 
{ 
   command.Parameters.Add("@Gender_Id",SqlDbType.Int).Value= DBNull.Value; 
} 
else 
{    
   command.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@Gender_Id", DDLGender.SelectedValue)); 
}
```

***Added* : Difference between `null` and `System.DbNull.Value`**

Well, `null` is not an instance of any type. Rather, it is an invalid reference.

However, `System.DbNull.Value`, is a valid reference to an instance of `System.DbNull` (`System.DbNull` is a singleton and `System.DbNull.Value` gives you a reference to the single instance of that class) that represents nonexistent<sup>*</sup> values in the database.

<sup>*We would normally say `null`, but I don't want to confound the issue.</sup>

So, there's a big conceptual difference between the two. The keyword `null` represents an invalid reference. The class `System.DbNull` represents a nonexistent value in a database field. In general, we should try avoid using the same thing (in this case `null`) to represent two very different concepts (in this case an invalid reference versus a nonexistent value in a database field).

Keep in mind, this is why a lot of people advocate using the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) in general, which is exactly what `System.DbNull` is an example of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (DDLGender.SelectedIndex == 0 )
{
   command.Parameters.Add("@Gender_Id", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
   command.Parameters.Add("@Gender_Id", (int)DDLGender.SelectedValue);
}
```

You don't **have** to specify the data type for parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using stored procedure for updating,
I think you can make the change in stored procedure to have default value to this INT column as NULL which will make this parameter optional. Then you can execute only the ELSE part here from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the above lines of code to :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = DDLGender.SelectedIndex!=0 ? (int)DDLGender.SelectedValue :  null });
```

The use of Null coalescing operator will do the null check. If the selectedItem is not null then that will be passed in as value otherwise null will be passed.